# will push notifications work if user has neither allowed nor "not allowed" push notifications for my app yet?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, ios7, apple-push-notifications, updating

I am currently updating my App, and I am planning on including Push notifications.

The main purpose for my push notification is to let users know that the app has been updated and they should check out the new features. Now with iOS7 automatically updating apps, users are less likely to open apps after they have been updated, let alone KNOW it has been updated. As a lot of users will just clear their notification centre's with out paying any attention.

So my question is...if a user has not launched my app yet to see the alert "[myApp] would like to send you Push Notifications" - Don't Allow / OK.

Will they see my push notification before they have had chance to allow or not allow?

Do push notifications work until "not allowed" has been pressed? Or do they not work until OK has been pressed???

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they never launched your app, your app never registered to Apple Push Notifications on their device, so you can't send them push notifications.

In addition, your server is not likely to have the device token for a device in which your app was never launched (since it's the app's job to send the device token to your server).

And if you push a notification to a device token of a device on which your app never registered to push notifications, the notification won't be delivered (even if the app is installed on the device), and that device token will eventually be returned to you in the feedback service.